# An array filtering issue with knockout and selectors

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an array of texts that I display in a `<select>`.

The texts may have different version no, and I want to filter the `<select>` based upon the latest version only.

I guess there are more elegant ways to do it (suggestions welcome), but I´ve chosen to use 2 `<select>`s set to alternate visibility depending on the checkbox.

The code is a hack, but the result looks pretty good. Unfortunately there´s a bug.

I have two observables indicating the selected option in their respective arrays:

```
self.SelectedText = ko.observable();
self.SelectedUnique = ko.observable();
```

Both have subscriptions, but I cannot link them together in both subscription, so I have chosen one to be indipendant on the other like this:

```
self.SelectedUnique.subscribe(function (text) {
    if (text) {
        self.SelectedText(text);
    }
});
```

However, the get out of sync.

Scenario 1: select text 1,2,3. [OK]
Scenario 2: select text 2; check "Latest versions only"

This causes no options ("Choose…") to be displayed. Not what I want.

It gets worse.

Scenario 3: uncheck; select text 3; Then check "Latest versions only" again.

Now the select option chosen is set to select option no 2 of the unfiltered.

There´s probably a simple issue. I just can´t make it work probably. Here´s the fiddle: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h5mt51gv/6/

All help and suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Are you familiar with writable computed observables?

Comment: You say what you do *not* want... but you do not say what you want. ;) What should be selected when an option becomes unavailable?

Comment: Good point Tomalak. when an option is unavailable I think the "Choose.." option is relevant. Alternatively the latest version could be chosen (together with an informative popup). I´m uncertain about this, but will handle this issue later.

Comment: @Cory Familiar and familiar. I have written some. Probably I have lots to learn. Do you have a spesific suggestion for me?

Comment: @AsleG Sorry, I didn't have time to build a deep understanding of your problem, but I hoped that maybe awareness of writable computed observables might help you out. Judging by the accepted answer, it looks like read-only observables will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have streamlined your approach:

- the `<select>` binds to a computed list of options (`visibleTextBatches`)
- this computed list depends on the state of the checkbox (`latestOnly`), effectively toggling between the full and the filtered list
- the filtered list (`latestTextBatches`) is another computed that holds the latest version for each group
- the `<select>` stores the actual selected `TextBatch` object in an observable (`selectedTextBatch`)
- there is a subscription to `visibleTextBatches` that causes the latest selectable `TextBatch` to become the current one when the list is filtered. When the list is unfiltered, it does nothing.

```js
function TextBatch(data) {
    this.textbatchId = data.textbatchId;
    this.parentId = data.parentId;
    this.version = data.version;
    this.title = ko.observable(data.title);
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // read up on the mapping plugin, too
    self.textBatches = ko.observableArray([
        new TextBatch({textbatchId: 1, parentId: 1, version: 1, title: "TB1.1"}),
        new TextBatch({textbatchId: 2, parentId: 1, version: 2, title: "TB1.2"}),
        new TextBatch({textbatchId: 3, parentId: 3, version: 1, title: "TB2.1"})
    ]);
    self.selectedTextBatch = ko.observable();
    self.latestOnly = ko.observable(false);
    self.latestTextBatchGroups = ko.computed(function () {
        var latest = {};
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.textBatches(), function (batch) {
            if (!latest.hasOwnProperty(batch.parentId) || 
                batch.version > latest[batch.parentId].version
            ) latest[batch.parentId] = batch;
        });
        return latest;
    });
    self.latestTextBatches = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.textBatches(), function (batch) {
            return batch === self.latestTextBatchGroups()[batch.parentId];
        });
    });
    self.visibleTextBatches = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.latestOnly() ? self.latestTextBatches() : self.textBatches();
    });
    self.visibleTextBatches.subscribe(function () {
        var selectedBatch = self.selectedTextBatch();
        if (selectedBatch && self.latestOnly()) {
            self.selectedTextBatch(
                self.latestTextBatchGroups()[selectedBatch.parentId]
            );
        }
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div>
    <select data-bind="
        options: visibleTextBatches, 
        optionsText: 'title',
        optionsCaption: 'Select...',
        value: selectedTextBatch
    " />
</div>

<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkLatestOnly" data-bind="checked: latestOnly" />
    <label for="chkLatestOnly">Latest only</label>
</div>

<hr />
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null,2)"></pre>
```

Comment: Nice @Tomalak Thank You!
I will have to change the logic in the "ko.utils.arrayForEach" fr the latestTextBatches-computed though, as parentId gets it´s number from the db-generated textbatchId, thus will not equal version.

Comment: I was making assumptions at this point, but I wanted to get the idea across.

Comment: Another thing: What is the difference between your "function ViewModel() " and (my) "var ViewModel = function()" ?

Comment: There is none. The one thing is a function statement and the other is a function expression, basically that's it. I like my constructors to be function statements, that's a matter of habit for me. Use function expressions if you like them better.

Comment: Thanks again. Looked at your website. Nice. Great comic strip. :)

Comment: I don't even have a website. Not sure where you were looking. o_O

Comment: Your bio here has a link. Thats not you?

Comment: Oh, my bio. Yeah, but that's just an XKCD, that's not my website.

Comment: That's a *huge* knowledge gap on your part. :) I do have some trouble imagining that there are people in the world who program computers and don't know XKCD.

Comment: Well. I´m not a programmer. I Thought that was pretty obvious ;)

Comment: have implemented part of your solution in my dev-site. Like it and it works. Still have some challenges with changing my "self.uniqueTBs"-logic into yours "self.latestTextBatchGroups" though...

Comment: @Tomalek Is it possible to hire you?

Comment: Another Q: why do you write: "latest[batch.parentId] = batch.version; " and not "latest.parentId = batch.version;" ?

Comment: Because `latest` does not have a property named `"parentId"`, it has a property named equal to the *value of* `parentId`. `latest.parentId` (or `latest["parentId"]`) do the former. `latest[parentId]` does the latter. Just set a breakpoint in your browser's debugging tools, step through the code line-by-line and see for yourself what's going on. (And no, it's not possible to hire me.)

Comment: @AsleG A few people hinted me that this is the right XKCD for [the situation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663072/an-array-filtering-issue-with-knockout-and-selectors/26664119?noredirect=1#comment41944990_26664119): http://xkcd.com/1053/ (many situations have their right XKCD). Have fun exploring them. :)

Comment: Nice, *Tomalek. :) I´ve learned a lot today thanks to you.
I have one more question regarding "latestTextBatches". I need to find the maxValue of "version" for each parentId, then I need to apply it as a property to the TextBatch-object. I would guess the place to do it is inside the ko.utils.arrayForEach-loop. However I need to listen to a change in the parentId, thus I need to compare the previous item (batch). How do I do that with an arrayForEach-loop?

Comment: **A)** *"I need to find the maxValue of "version" for each parentId"* — my code does that in `latestTextBatchGroups`, have a look. **B)** *"However I need to listen to a change in the parentId"* — No problem. Make `parentId` observable (it isn't in my example) and use `parentId()` in every place where I used `parentId`. Knockout's dependency tracking should do the rest, no further changes necessary. When you change the `parentId` of any text batch, all the other dependencies throughout your viewmodel are re-calculated automatically.